# How can i use two where statements before a subquery and in a subquery

Tags: mysql, subquery, where-clause

I am trying to use two where statements in my SQL query one query to filter on a company name and the other one in the subquery. But it keeps giving me errors

My code:

```
select *
from products c
where c.company = "Apple"
and
where c.id in (select bi.component_id
from category ct
join items bi
on ct.id = bi.id
where ct.id in (1,2,3)
)
```

I only wanna filter on Apple but the moment in run my script it gives me an error

Comment: You cant use where like that

Comment: How do i need to use it then?

Answer (score 1):

You have two "where" you only need one

```
select *
from products c
where c.company = "Apple"
and c.id in (select bi.component_id
from category ct
join items bi
on ct.id = bi.id
where ct.id in (1,2,3)
)
```

Answer (score -1):

I Think you should try 
select *
from products c
where c.company = "Apple"
and
where c.id in (select bi.component_id
from category ct
join items bi
on ct.id = bi.id
)

hope it worked fine for you